# shorthand for feeding contents of multiple files to the stdin of a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, io-redirection

Let's say I have a script called `script`, that reads from `stdin` and spits out some results to the screen.

If I wanted to feed it contents of one file, I would have typed:

```
$ ./script < file1.txt
```

But what if I want to feed the contents of the multiple files to the script the same way, is it at all possible? The best I came up with so far was:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > combined.txt && ./script < combined.txt
```

Which uses two commands and creates a temp file. Is there a way to do the same thing but bypassing creating the combined file?

Comment: Switch to `zsh` and you'll be able to run `cmd <file1 <file2 ... <fileN` ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `cat` and a pipe:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN | ./script
```

`cat` and `./script` in that case run concurrently and the data is fed via some IPC mechanism which in practice is either a pipe or socket pair depending on the shell and system.

In the zsh shell, you can also do:

```
./script < file1 < file2 ... < fileN
```

Which works in the same way. When stdin (or any other file descriptor) is redirected for input more than once, zsh replaces it with the reading end of a pipe, and implements a `cat`-like process internally to feed the inputs in sequence through the other end of that pipe.

Note that those approaches don't work if `./script` expects to be able to seek within the file, such as when it needs to read it several times after rewinding to the beginning or to map it in memory (by way of `mmap()` for instance) as that can't be done with a pipe nor socket pair. In that case, you'll need a temporary *regular* (*seekable*) file and the two commands (`cat` and `./script`) can't run concurrently. In `zsh`, that can be made easier with the `=(cmd)` form of process substitution which expands to the path of a temporary file that contains the output of `cmd` and is automatically removed afterwards:

```
./script < =(cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN)
```

The `fish` shell has something similar with:

```
./script < (cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN | psub -f)
```

Comment: Useful use of cat award!

Comment: @Bruce Ediger: I assume you were just pointing out a way to use `join` without a temp file, but just to make it clear to the reader:  `cat f1 f2` does not produce the same output as `join f1 f2`

Comment: @fred thanks for pointing this out -- I used `join` in my example because I was playing with it before; in reality, for my example I was using `cat`.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use a pipe, you can use input redirection with process substitution:

```bash
./script < <(cat file1 file2)
```

Comment: Do you know of any reason where the script will only receive / output nothing (literally `""`)?

Comment: `<(...)` uses a pipe internally. The main different in bash is that `cat` is started in background and the shell doesn't wait for its termination. Here it has no benefit over using a proper pipe. You'd only use it in bash for commands (such as builtins or functions that modify the shell environment) that  need to run in the current shell process to work around the fact that in bash (contrary to zsh or ksh93), in `A | B`, `B` also runs in a child process (though see the `lastpipe` option in recent versions of  bash)

Answer (score 4):

To add on @Jonah Braun's answer, if you ever need to add process output into your script as well, i.e. your file might not be on your disk but accessed via `URL` using `curl` or a similar tool.

Something like this could be used to get `stdout` of multiple processes and use them in a script via `stdin`

This will be the script to handle input
Contents of `multi-input.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

Now test it:

```
$ ./multi-input.sh < <(cat <(echo process 1) <(echo process 2) <(echo process 3))
```

Output:

```
process 1
process 2
process 3
```

`<()` turns process into a virtual `file` using `fd` if you will, so `<` is needed to read it. `cat` itself doesn't need it because it does what it does, concatenates files, virtual or real.